# How to get require message in a test case? Truffle test

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

For instance I'm running testcase for a smart contract and it's test function has required validation.

```
function test(uint _id) public pure returns(bool){
    require(_id == 0 ,"not valid!");
    return true;
}
```

But when I execute the test case it throwing an error

> AssertionError: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction:
>   revert

Test cases:

```
it("Adding test into blockchain", async () => {                               

    const result = await Instance.test(1);                        

    expect(result).to.be.not.equal('null');            
});

it("Adding zero Id test into blockchain", async () => {                               

    const result = await Instance.test(0);                        

    //TODO: get error message   
});
```

Comment: what's your test block?

Comment: @BadrBellaj: question updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will fire an exception

you have in the first test    `require(_id == 0 ,"not valid!");`

and you feed it _id=1 (test(1))
therefore an exception will be raised.

either test with test(0)

or

check try/catch the exception as follow :

```
try {
     await Instance.test(1); 
        } catch (error) {
            Error = error;
        }
        assert.notEqual(Error, undefined, 'Error must be thrown');
        assert.isAbove(Error.message.search('VM Exception while processing transaction: revert'), -1, 'Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert');

    });
```

Comment: *either test with test(0)*, but I want to create negative test(s) to make sure smart contract would handle the things appropriately. *check try/catch the exception* any example would be really helpful, currently I added catch block, though it gives an exception.

Comment: I also tried to make library like [this](https://github.com/JoinColony/colonyNetwork/blob/develop/helpers/test-helper.js#L72) but seems import having issue with truffle.. don't know how other implemented.

Comment: check the try/catch block i've proposed

Comment: Thanks, but is this recommended approach? it seems awful test case! *p.s I'm from server side background :D*

Comment: what's awful in it? :p
you raise an error and you check the message nothing harmfull

Comment: What if you have a stack of `require` statements and want to test which one triggered during a test. Without the message it seems impossible. Also, if you can't get the require message, what purpose does it even serve?

Answer (score 0):

you can either use truffle-assertions with

```
npm install truffle-assertions
```

in your test code

```
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
await truffleAssert.reverts(Instance.test(1));
```

or you can use a simple try catch with

```
    try {
        await Instance.test(1);
    } catch(err) {
        Error = err
    }
    assert.equal(Error.reason, 'not valid!');
```